# Receiving error while compiling with paper rock scissors

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compile this code but I get an "not all code paths return a value" in judgeRockPaperScissors().  I need the three methods to work in the main method. I not sure what is wrong. I was having issues with converting int to strings as well. Any help would be great! Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class RockPaperScissors
{
static string response;
static string respond;
static string player1Sel;
static int player2Sel;
static int result;
static Random numberGenerator = new Random();  //Generates a random number.

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Do you want to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?");//  User writes yes or anything else.
    respond = Console.ReadLine();
    respond = respond.ToUpper();  //Makes the responce uppercase.
    while (respond == "YES")
    {  //Beginning of "while loop".
        player1Sel = promptForInput();
        player2Sel = generateAutoSelect();
        result = judgeRockPaperScissors();
        switch (result)
        {
            case 00:
                Console.WriteLine("Draw!");
                break;
            case 12:
                Console.WriteLine("Paper covers rock. Player 2 Wins!");
                break;
            case 23:
                Console.WriteLine("Scissors cut paper. Player 2 Wins!");
                break;
            case 31:
                Console.WriteLine("Rock smashes scissors. Player 2 Wins!");
                break;
            case 13:
                Console.WriteLine("Rock smashes scissors. Player 1 Wins!");
                break;
            case 21:
                Console.WriteLine("Paper covers rock. Player 1 Wins!");
                break;
            case 32:
                Console.WriteLine("Scissors cut paper. Player 1 Wins!");
                break;
        }// End of switch.

        Console.Write("Do you want to play again?");//  Where the player decides to play again.
        respond = Console.ReadLine();
        respond = respond.ToUpper();

    }  //End of "while loop".

}  //End of Main.

private static int judgeRockPaperScissors()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public static string promptForInput()
{
    Console.Write("Player one, make a selection. Type 1=rock, 2=paper, or 3=scissors and press enter: ");
    player1Sel = Console.ReadLine();
    if (player1Sel == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must select a valid choice.");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else
    if (int.Parse(player1Sel) < 1 | int.Parse(response) > 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(response + " - is not a valid choice.");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    return player1Sel;
}// End of promptForInput.

public static int generateAutoSelect()
{
    int player2Sel = numberGenerator.Next(1, 4);//Generates random number between 1 and 3.

    if (player2Sel == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Player2 chose rock.");
    }
    else
        if (player2Sel == 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Player2 chose paper.");
    }
    else
            if (player2Sel == 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Player2 chose scissors.");
    }
    return player2Sel;
} //   End of generateAutoSelect.

public static string judgeRockPaperScissors(int player1Sel, int player2Sel)
{
    if (player1Sel == player2Sel)
    { return "00"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 1 && player2Sel == 2)
    { return "12"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 2 && player2Sel == 3)
    { return "23"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 3 && player2Sel == 1)
    { return "31"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 1 && player2Sel == 3)
    { return "13"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 2 && player2Sel == 1)
    { return "21"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 3 && player2Sel == 2)
    { return "32"; }
}// End of judgeRockPaperScissors.
```

}  // End of class.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler does not know that you have handled all possible cases in your `if/else if` blocks because the range of `int` is far more than 0-2. The easiest way to get your code compiling is to add a generic else block:

```
...
else 
{
  throw new ArgumentException("Player selections out of range");
}
```

Since the input is invalid throw an exception.
On a side note, using strings the way you are is definitely not the right approach.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The program compiles now, but when run the program I still get an error "Unhandled Exception: System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented." from judgeRockPaperScissors(). BradleyDotNET, I assume that your comment about my use of strings is part of my problem. Hopefully I can figure it out.

Comment: @IsaacElder That's coming from your `private static int judgeRockPaperScissors()` version. The strings are bad style/practice but unrelated to that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Update the function to return null if no conditions are met:

```
public static string judgeRockPaperScissors(int player1Sel, int player2Sel)
{
    if (player1Sel == player2Sel)
    { return "00"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 1 && player2Sel == 2)
    { return "12"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 2 && player2Sel == 3)
    { return "23"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 3 && player2Sel == 1)
    { return "31"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 1 && player2Sel == 3)
    { return "13"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 2 && player2Sel == 1)
    { return "21"; }
    else if (player1Sel == 3 && player2Sel == 2)
    { return "32"; }
    return null;
}
```

That way it will always return with something.  You'll also want to add a null check on the result variable in your main function to make sure it didn't return null.

Comment: https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare better to throw an exception explicitly so you know what went wrong in the program.

Comment: I agree, BradleyDotNET 's answer is much better.  Thank you for the link and info though @silentsod